# Skip KeyboardNavigation for all Controls in a Panel or Grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, focus, gridpanel

Normaly KeyboardFocus will be skipped, when the controls IsTabStop property is set to false. But there is no such porperty for the Grid or other Panels. I tried the Attached Property KeybordNavigation.IsTabStop, but this neither had the affect of skipping the Keyboard Focus for the hole grid.

I want to skip all controls within a grid when one of the grid descendant controls will normaly reseive the focus. Has somebody experience with this an can provide an solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. On your Grid you need to use the attached property:

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
```

Comment: That works as needed, partialy :)
We now can skip the Grid! But now, when I set focus to one of the controls inside this grid, it will always jump out of the grid, but I need the focus to stay in the grid if someone intentionaly set the focus there!